# Java SE: Open Web Page and Click a Button

Tags: java

I have a Java 7 program (using WebStart technology, for Windows 7/8 computers only).

I need to add a function so that my program clicks a button on a page with known URL (https).

Some people suggest WebKit SWT, but I went to their site and they say that the project was discontinued. (http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs.html)

Other people say that JxBrowser is the only option but it looks like it's over $1,300 which is crazy. (http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/onlinedemo/)

I'm looking for something simple, free, lightweight, and able to open HTTPS link, parse HTML, access a button through DOM and click it. Perhaps some JavaScript too, in case there are JS handlers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: JavaFx ships with java 7 and has a webview object which is basically a browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may be looking for [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) -- a *"GUI-Less browser for Java programs"*.

Here's a sample code that opens `google.com`, searches for `"htmlunit"` using the form and prints the number of results.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

public class HtmlUnitFormExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");

        HtmlInput searchBox = page.getElementByName("q");
        searchBox.setValueAttribute("htmlunit");

        HtmlSubmitInput googleSearchSubmitButton = 
                          page.getElementByName("btnG"); // sometimes it's "btnK"
        page=googleSearchSubmitButton.click();

        HtmlDivision resultStatsDiv =
                                page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='resultStats']");

        System.out.println(resultStatsDiv.asText()); // About 309,000 results
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

Other options are:

- [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/): Will open a browser like Firefox and operate it.
- [Watij](http://watij.com/): Also will open a browser, but in its own window.
- [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org): Good parser. No JavaScript, though.

Comment: HtmlUnit does not open any browser, it emulates one. It is full Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of difficult to understand what you want.  If you have a webstart app and want to open a link in the browser, you can use the `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI)` method.

```
public void openLinkInBrowser(ActionEvent event){

    try {
        URI uri = new URI(WEB_ADDRESS);
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);

    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
        //System.out.println("THROW::: make sure we handle browser error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: what about clicking the button? does it allow that?

Comment: Yes, the method called using the ActionEvent that's passed to it could easily be triggered by a button.