# HTML Insertion and Button Press

Tags: java, html, insertion

I'm trying to make a Java program that inserts information into the login page of a website (http://newcas.gbdioc2.org/public/home.html), and then downloads the HTML from the website, analyzes it, and makes it look good in a GUI.

I've figured out the HTML download part, but I need help with figuring out a way to insert information into the fields on the login page at the URL shown above.

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746138/java-se-open-web-page-and-click-a-button) is what I'd use.

Comment: @JonathanVanDam, the password field doesn't have a "name", and I can't use insertion without a field name. Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in PHP.
All you would have to do is set the inputs to this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $USER; ?>" />
<input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $PASS; ?>" />
```

To get the info you'd have to use a little more PHP and read up on PHP form handling.

Comment: I can't manipulate the PHP on the webpage if that's what you're saying.

Comment: @fedorp1 Does your server not support PHP?

Comment: I'm pinging another server that I do not have the control of. The link of the server above is not mine, and I cannot tell whether it supports PHP or not. Everything that is on the webpage above cannot be manipulated to support PHP or not. It must be analyzed the way it is. Here is another URL that can be analyzed, if you look at the URL, the username and password fields are the exact fields that I need manipulate.